# Automation of legal description( section - township- Range - Location)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, plss, township-range-section

Referring to the snap below, i want to automate the legal decription like W2NE, NENE, NWNE and so on... available inputs are Section, Township and Range info. I am using QGIS 2.8.3. I have so many legal descriptions like this(snap attached below) which we are doing manually till now.

How can I automate this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to automate? Please describe your current process and the rules you apply. If you need a description one by one a Python script may be helpful. If it is possible to generate all at once a Process Model may be appropriate.

Comment: What I have:

an excel file with the names of properties within an area that is part of the PLSS in which Township/Range, Section and QQ sections are used.
Here are some examples of the individual legal descriptions:
W2NE - west half of northeast quarter in section - 12, Township - 13N and Range- 12W

Comment: The excel data contains these fields. attached in the snap

Comment: What I want to do:

I would like to write a script in QGIS 2.8.3 that goes through the excel table and adds features to a feature class based on the legal descriptions of every property.

Comment: @Detlev , Could you please share the script that works in QGIS 2.8.3 for the automation said above?

Comment: Please add an example on how a row of the Excel table (upper image)  is related to a single or aggregated geometry (lower image). I didn't understand yet, how you get a geometry feature from a string like W2NE. You obviously are applying some algorithm or business logic, but its not clear for someone not being used to your problem

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you need, but if you have azimuths and distances you can use the plugin [Azimuth and Distance Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/). You can install it from the QGIS repository. It works only with QGIS 2.x. There are some instructions in this page: [QGIS: Azimuth and Distance Plugin](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-azimuth-distance-plugin)

Comment: No, this is not the one i am looking for, these are used when metes and bounds descrption given

Comment: @GeoJohn , the same you did in ArcGIS, is this possible in QGIS please share the script